# Have there been any mechanisms proposed for normalization in probabilistic population codes?

Tags: neuroscience, theoretical-neuroscience, bayesian

I heard a talk yesterday by Dora Angelaki about multi-sensory integration.  Part of the talk was about bayesian inference with multiple noisy sources of information.  I know that there has been a lot of theoretical work done on bayesian inference and population coding, but I was wondering if there have been any biological mechanisms proposed for the population activity normalization necessary for these computations?

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you mean by a biological mechanism. If you mean that there should be a protein cascade that implements normalization, that doesn't seem plausible, in my opinion. Normalization in probabilistic population codes is just one of many computations that can be performed in a neural system.

If you're okay with the notion that there's nothing biologically unique about normalization, then [Normalization for probabilistic inference with neurons](http://compneuro.uwaterloo.ca/files/publications/eliasmith.2011.pdf) (a paper written by my supervisor, Chris Eliasmith) proposes a spiking neural network performs normalization on probability density functions.